# How to directly map an object class from angular 2 to to web api using JSON?

Tags: c#, json, angular, asp.net-web-api, angular2-routing

I have a model class I created in angular 2 to track fields. This same class also exists as a model in my webapi project.

```
export class People {
    Name: string;
    Phone: string;
    Date: date;}

export class Address {
 street: string,
 zip: string,
}
```

in my service I send this to my webapi controller

```
getPeopleData(peopleModel: People, addressmodel: Address)
{
let headers = new headers(...)
data = {
   "p": peopleModel,
   "a": addressModel
}
let body = JSON.stringify(data);

return this.http.post(url, body, {headers: headers})
.map((response: Response)=> ...
}
```

finally in my controller

```
public JArray GetPeopleData([FromBody]JObject models)
{
   var modelPeople = models["p"].ToObject<People>();
   var modelAddress = models["a"].ToObject<Address>();

}
```

modelPeople and modeAddress doesn't map. How can I get my model to map directly.

All I get are a bunch of null fields when there is a string of data in the JObject.

EDIT:
I created a container class that holds the objects of People and Address

```
public class Container
{
   public People people {get; set;}
   public Address addresss {get; set;}
}
```

I then passed in the object to the Container and my results are still null

```
 public JArray GetPeopleData([FromBody]Container container)
    {
       var modelPeople = container.people;
       var modelAddress = container.address;

    }
```

both have all values of null.

I dont get it I feel like I am so close but something is missing

Comment: In Web API, just accept it as an object. Another words, expose a REST endpoint that accepts an object as the parameter. The object will serialize/deserialize to JSON for you, so no need to worry about how to map it over, etc. etc.

Comment: Im confused. what should my parmeter look like in the public JArray GetPeopleData([FromBody]JObject models) and what should i pass to it?

Comment: Yeah, the JArray is the problem. Just define the plain old C# object as the parameter.

Comment: I updated the code above to directly accept a container object that holds both classes. All of the values still comes back as null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello it works for me

```
//This is a Gobal object
 result = {
    modelPeople: '',
    modelAddress: ''
 }

constructor( private _http: Http ) {

}
getJsonModel() {
    promise = await this._http.get(URL).toPromise().then(
                res => {
                    this.result= res.json();
                }
    );
}
```

Comment: I got it., Im an idiot. My properties in my people and address models weren't public. Its always the simple things